# How to Reduce a Pandas DataFrame By Row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Using python/pandas, I am trying to reduce dataframe rows to an array which contains the column names of the original dataframe, if the original entry is True.

```
(Pdb) df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[True,False], [True,True], [False,True]]),columns=['x','y'])
(Pdb) df
       x      y
0   True  False
1   True   True
2  False   True
(Pdb) df_out = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['x'], ['x','y'], ['y']]),columns=['z'])
(Pdb) df_out
        z
0     [x]
1  [x, y]
2     [y]
```

I've looked into apply() and applymap() with a lambda, but I'm having problems accessing the columns from the original dataframe `df`, as I don't know how to bind to external variables for access within the lambda.

There must be a more direct, succinct, functional approach that I am missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution with list comprehension with convert values to numpy arrays by [`DataFrame.to_numpy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html) (fastest):

```
cols = df.columns.to_numpy()
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'z':[cols[x] for x in df.to_numpy()]})
```

Or you can use [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with `axis=1` (slowier):

```
df1 = df.apply(lambda x: x.index[x].tolist(), axis=1).to_frame('z')
```

Solution with [`DataFrame.dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) is used mainly if need string output, here is added [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) for lists (slowier):

```
df1 = df.dot(df.columns + ',').str.rstrip(',').str.split(',').to_frame('z')
print (df)
        z
0     [x]
1  [x, y]
2     [y]
```

Comment: Nice, your first solution is nearly 10x faster than my answer.  And 20x faster than your second solution (I tried with 10k rows).  And 40x faster than sammywemmy's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can run [compress](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.compress.html) on the boolean rows to get your output :

```
from itertools import product

df['out'] = [np.compress(cond,col).tolist() 
             for cond, col 
             in product(df.to_numpy(),[df.columns])]

        x     y     out
0   True    False   [x]
1   True    True    [x, y]
2   False   True    [y]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it this way:

```
df.apply(lambda row: df.columns[row.values].tolist(), axis=1)
```

It gives you a Series (which of course you can store into a DataFrame as `z`):

```
0       [x]
1    [x, y]
2       [y]
dtype: object
```